# How to use Jenssegers Optimus in Laravel Models?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Jenssegers Optimus package to obfuscate my URLS.

Currently, I am calling it in every single controller that deals with get requests. Problem is, I need to constantly encode and decode my IDs in almost all methods in my controllers.

E.g.:

```
use Jenssegers\Optimus\Optimus;

    class ResponseController extends Controller
    {
        protected $optimus;

        public function __construct(Optimus $opt)
        {
            $this->optimus = $opt;

        }

        public function index()
        {

            $labels = Label->get();

            foreach ($labels as $key => $label){
              $label->id = $this->optimus->encode($label->id);
              $labels[$key] = $label;
            }

            return view('responses/index', compact('labels'));
        }

        public function show($id)
        {
            $id = $this->optimus->decode($id);

            $label =  Label::get($id);

       }

    }
```

I thought of creating Accessors & Mutators to always encrypt the IDs of the models I need to obfuscate in the URL. So I'd put them in a trait to reuse the code. I tried:

```
  use Jenssegers\Optimus\Optimus;

    trait EncodeId{

       public function getIdAttribute($value, Optimus $optimus)
       {

        return $optimus->encode($value);
       }

    }
```

Then I added this trait to my model. However, Laravel would throw an error complaining about Optimus $optimus in the method definition. It said $optimus was expected to be a type of Jenssegers\Optimus\Optimus even though I am declaring it. That works for controllers just fine, but it doesn't work for models apparently. Or I shouldn't try to use a trait in this case.

Here's the actual error:

```
FatalThrowableError in EncodeId.php line 10:
Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Label::getIdAttribute() must be an instance of Jenssegers\Optimus\Optimus, none given, called in /home/../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 2734
```

It would be really nice if I could use Optimus obfuscation on the model level rather than calling its encode and decode functions multiple times in my controllers.

There's another package called FakeID that is meant to do that. I tried to implement it in my project but it didn't work. I am pretty sure I could handle it myself since it seems a simple task.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error so we can comment on it

Comment: @Gayan Sure. I didn't put it there because I've lost my trait file. Soon I'll recreat it to reproduce the error. Once I get home I'll update my question. Thanks

Comment: @Gayan I just added the full error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get mutators (AKA accessors) are called along with a single argument. That's why you are getting `expected to be a type of Jenssegers\Optimus\Optimus` error as  `Jenssegers\Optimus\Optimus` is not injected by framework when calling acessors or mutators (like controllers does).

Just read this snippet from source code (line [2632](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2632)):

```
  public function getAttributeValue($key)
    {
        $value = $this->getAttributeFromArray($key);
        // If the attribute has a get mutator, we will call that then return what
        // it returns as the value, which is useful for transforming values on
        // retrieval from the model to a form that is more useful for usage.
        if ($this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
            return $this->mutateAttribute($key, $value);
        }

        //...    
    }
```

And now the call to `$this->mutateAttribute($key, $value);` (line [2736](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2736))

```
 protected function mutateAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        return $this->{'get'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute'}($value);
    }
```

Did you understand now?
Acessor/get mutator are called along with just one argument: `$value`.

**Solution**

You could to try something like this:

```
public function getIdAttribute($value)
{
    return app(Optimus::class)->encode($value);
}
```

Invoking Optimus instance from container (`app()`) would do the trick.

Comment: Oh.  Actually I thought that could be the issue. I saw the doc example having just one argument passed, I wasn't sure though if it was only allowed one argument. I tried to use encode as a static method for Optimus, it clearly didn't work. I'm gonna test your solution once I get home.

Comment: @Leandro I haven't not tested the proposed solution, but getting Optimus instance from container is the way to go. --- Eu não testei ainda, mas obter a instância do Optimus do container é a direção certa.